# ZedGraph - How to reverse Y asix in line chart

Tags: c#, zedgraph

By default, the `Y` axis will start from bottom in `ZedGraph`.

Now, I want to have a chart will look:

```
   y
 0 |
10 |
20 |
30 |
40 |--------------x
```

Is it possible to reverse `Y` asix?

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by setting `YAxis.Scale.IsReverse = true;`

Comment: 6 min for a self answer? That's quite fast :)